# ​Universe as a projection of something

Tags: universe, projectile

Who has proposed this and is there an experimental proof?
Where can I start to learn about this?

Comment: I believe you refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle

Comment: there is a bijection between information contained in a (hyper-)sphere and those in its (hyper-)surface. That's all. The model was first used for black holes. When applied to (our ) universe , it needs the poetic license to stand up ...

Comment: The good thing about the holographic universe hypothesis is that it can be tested experimentally. The Holometer collaboration has just published a first paper that seems to exclude one prediction about high frequency gravitational background noise with almost 4.6 sigma. Not looking good, so far. The same thing is probably also true for some of the predicted Planck scale physics. There seems to be nothing there, there.

Comment: [The holometer experiment appears to have been a triumph of hope over common sense that ended up proving nothing](http://backreaction.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/what-fermilabs-holometer-experiment.html).

Comment: @JohnRennie: Depends on which end of the stick one is... I would characterize it as the first in a line of experiments which will demonstrate that the Planck scale was a naive concept. As for why Sabine Hossenfelder has this extremely emotional reaction to somebody else's experiment... I can't tell. There is definitely something outright human going on there that has nothing to do with physics. For one thing she accuses the PI of not having a theory... string theorists and holographers don't have theories, either. They don't even seem to have testable hypotheses at this moment.

Comment: @CuriousOne regarding the accusation of lack of theory: *Hogan didn’t have a theory. It’s not that I am just grumpy – he said so himself: “It's a slight cheat because I don't have a theory,” as quoted by Michael Moyer in a 2012 Scientific American article.* From the article Mr. Rennie linked.

Comment: @Asher: the definition of a scientific theory is that of a large body of theoretical work that explains a wide range of observations. Neither string theory nor the holographic principle can be used to explain anything, at this moment. They are not theories, either. Worse, still, they are not even testable hypotheses. This experiment, on the other hand, has established a new and so far untested floor for gravitational waves in a high frequency regime. THAT happens to be real physics. String theory and holography are not.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a cue from the link http://motherboard.vice.com/read/there-is-growing-evidence-that-our-universe-is-a-giant-hologram or from the book holographic Universe

Comment: "Search for Space-Time Correlations from the Planck Scale with the Fermilab Holometer", Aaron S. Chou et al. This is a demonstration why one should never trust "pop science" books and links.